# Getting the index of a failed Task after calling TTask.WaitForAny

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Consider the following example:

```
 t1 := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      sleep(Random(1000) + 100);
      raise Exception.Create('Error Message 1');
    end
  );

  t2 := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      sleep(Random(1000) + 100);
      raise Exception.Create('Error Message 2');
    end
  );

  res := -1;
  try
    res:= TTask.WaitForAny([t1, t2]);
  except
  end;

  write('Index: ' + intToStr(res)); // Prints "-1"
  readln;
```

When one of the tasks fails WaitForAny throws an exception and the res variable is not assigned the index of the completed task. Instead it contains "-1" (assigned earlier).

In C# (TPL) `Task.WaitAny` also throws an exception, but it returns the index of the failed task.

Is there a way to get the RES variable assigned or get the index of the failed task?

Comment: I expect you have to keep track of that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so this is a language behavior? i.e. when a function throws an exception the Result assignment never happens?

Comment: Function return value is undefined if function raises. Same in all languages, including C#. So no, I don't think that WaitAny does return anything if it raises.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, yeah, WaitAny in C# doesn't throw an exception and returns the index of the first completed task. So my solution would be to iterate over the tasks and get the first that has completed.

Comment: In the question you talk about TPL `WaitForAny`. Do you mean `WaitAny`? I'm trying to write an answer here, but I am wondering whether we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: It was a mistake. I gave an example of Task.WaitAny in TPL.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> In C# (TPL) `Task.WaitAny` also throws an exception, but it returns the index of the failed task.

That's not true. Consider the following C# program:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("task 1"); });
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("task 2"); });
            int index = Task.WaitAny(new Task[] { t1, t2 });
            Console.WriteLine(index);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Both tasks throw exceptions, but `WaitAny` does not. It returns the index value of whichever task completed first, even if that task threw an exception.

By contrast, the Delphi `TTask.WaitForAny` method will raise an exception if the first task to complete does so by raising an exception. In that case, since function return values are not assigned when the function raises an exception, you will need to find a different way to identify the task that caused `WaitForAny` to return. For instance, here is a rather lame way to do it:

```pascal
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Threading;

type
  ETaskException = class(Exception)
  private
    FTaskIndex: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(const Msg: string; const TaskIndex: Integer);
    property TaskIndex: Integer read FTaskIndex;
  end;

constructor ETaskException.Create(const Msg: string; const TaskIndex: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(Msg);
  FTaskIndex := TaskIndex;
end;

var
  t1, t2: ITask;
  i, res: Integer;

begin
 t1 := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      sleep(150);
      raise ETaskException.Create('Task failed', 0);
    end
  );

  t2 := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      sleep(100);
      raise ETaskException.Create('Task failed', 1);
    end
  );

  try
    res := TTask.WaitForAny([t1, t2]);
    Writeln('Task succeeded, index ' + IntToStr(res));
  except
    on E:EAggregateException do begin
      for i := 0 to E.Count-1 do begin
        WriteLn('Task failed, index ' + 
          IntToStr((E.InnerExceptions[i] as ETaskException).TaskIndex));
      end;
    end;
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Although I've looped over the aggregate exceptions here, I believe that there will only ever be one inner exception with `WaitForAny`.

You may be better off just looping over the tasks looking for one that has `Status` equal to `TTaskStatus.Exception`.